# Cannot find module './lib/should'

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, should.js

i have a test code  and trying to run it

```
var should = require("should")
describe('Array', function(){
  describe('#indexOf()', function(){
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present',function(){
      [1,2,3].indexOf(5).should.equal(-1);
      [1,2,3].indexOf(0).should.equal(-1);
    })
  })
})
```

when i run it  i am getting error

```
Error: Cannot find module './lib/should'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ritesh/projects/passport-topcoder/node_modules/should/index.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ritesh/projects/passport-topcoder/test/module.test.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:152:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:149:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:306:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:348:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

i included mocha and should in package.json but why i am facing this error .should is showing in my node modules also.please guideline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue, and I think it is because `should` package has been updated two hours ago (and it may have broken something).

```
npm install should@1.3.0
```

did the trick.

EDIT

Version 2.0.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: is there any bug in 1.3.0 also ??i am facing issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303240/object-object-has-no-method-type

Comment: @Nitin I don't know, but version 2.0.1 is online, so you should definitely give it a try!

Comment: Remember to install as a dev dependency

Answer (score 2):

It simply means `should` from the NPM is not installed. Simply use

```
sudo npm install should
```

This means that it should install `should` from the node package manage.

Hope it makes stuff clearer.

Cheers.

Comment: Hey, this isn't a good idea, because it's not portable to other installs of your projects code.  If I git checkout the project and try to run the tests, the tests shouldn't require me to npm install -g.