# Object #<Object> has no method 'type'

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, should.js

My test code is

```
var strategy = require('../lib');
var should = require("should");
describe('passport-twitter', function() {

  it('should export Strategy constructor directly from package', function() {
    console.log('strategy is',strategy);
    strategy.should.have.type('function');
  });

  it('should export Strategy constructor', function() {
    strategy.Strategy.should.have.type('function');
  });

});
```

and when i run this test.it is giving me error

```
1) passport-twitter should export Strategy constructor directly from package:
     TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'type'
      at Context.<anonymous> (/home/ritesh/projects/passport-topcoder/test/module.test.js:7:26)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:211:32)
      at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:358:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:404:12
      at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:284:14)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:293:7
      at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:237:23)
      at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:261:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

  2) passport-twitter should export Strategy constructor:
     TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'type'
      at Context.<anonymous> (/home/ritesh/projects/passport-topcoder/test/module.test.js:11:35)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:211:32)
      at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:358:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:404:12
      at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:284:14)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:293:7
      at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:237:23)
      at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:261:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

but the type method is specified in documentation.how to get rid of this error.please help a bit.

instead of this when i try to run

aa

```
var strategy = require('..');
var should = require("should");
describe('passport-twitter', function() {

  it('should export', function() {
    console.log('strategy is',strategy);
   'xxxx'.should.have.type('function');
  });

});
```

still i am getting the error

```
 1) passport-twitter should export:
     TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'type'
      at Context.<anonymous> (/home/ritesh/projects/passport-topcoder/test/module.test.js:7:23)
      at Test.Runnable.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:211:32)
      at Runner.runTest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:358:10)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:404:12
      at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:284:14)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:293:7
      at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:237:23)
      at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:261:5)
      at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Comment: It is unclear without knowing what you requiring into strategy variable

Comment: in console logs  strategy is { version: '1.0.0',
  Strategy: 
   { [Function: Strategy]
     super_: { [Function: OAuth2Strategy] super_: [Function: Strategy] } } }
 we are getting this .

Comment: even its giving me same error on a string as i updated

Answer (score 0):

`should.js` has the following syntax:

```
'xxxx'.should.be.type('string');
```

[Should.js documentation # type](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/#type)